# Read a web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can I use JavaScript, or any other non-server script, to read a web page? I'd like my local HTML file (with JavaScript code) to read a internal web page, which is hosted on a web server, and get its entire source code.

I tried XMLHttpRequest, but I am facing cross-domain issue. Any solution to this? Or any other non-server script that I can use? I already have a few JavaScript functions that I'd be using so want to use your suggested solution and my existing JavaScript code together.

Comment: what do you mean by "internal web page, which is hosted on a web server" are you running a local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) so to get the data from other servers we have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the sample in this document.
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/